# Selecting only values where a specific combination of 2 columns is present?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'timesheets' that I would like to insert blank records into based upon another pivot table called employees_projects (referencing employeeID and projectID). I want to generate an INSERT/UPDATE query into the timesheets table that will essentially use EmployeeID as an input to then display all the projects that the employee has assigned to them via the employees_projects table.

For example, an employee named Foo has employeeID of 1. There is a project named Bar that has projectID of 1. There exists a record in employees_projects with employeeID=1 and projectID=1. Now when Foo loads the timesheets php file (after already storing his $employeeID within the session), I would like to only populate a timesheet record for project Bar. Here is the php code I am using to build the timesheet table, you can see the columns I am using:

```
 $result = $conn->query("select timesheets.id, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, WeekEndingDate, Notes, Submitted, EmployeeID, ProjectID, projects.ProjectName from timesheets INNER JOIN projects ON timesheets.ProjectID=projects.id WHERE EmployeeID=$eId");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($id,$Mon,$Tues,$Wed,$Thurs,$Fri,$WeekEndingDate,$notes,$employeeId,$projectId,$projectName);
              $id = $row['id'];
              $Mon = $row['Monday'];
              $Tues = $row['Tuesday'];
              $Wed = $row['Wednesday'];
              $Thurs = $row['Thursday'];
              $Fri = $row['Friday'];
              $WeekEndingDate= $row['WeekEndingDate'];
              $notes = $row['Notes'];
              $employeeId = $row['EmployeeID'];
              $projectId = $row['ProjectID'];
              $projectName = $row['ProjectName'];

              echo '<tr><td>'. $projectId.'</td><td>'.$projectName.'</td><td><input type="text" id="Mon" value='.$Mon.'></td><td><input type="text" id="Mon" value='.$Tues.'></td><td><input type="text" id="Mon" value='.$Wed.'></td><td><input type="text" id="Mon" value='.$Thurs.'></td><td><input type="text" id="Mon" value='.$Fri.'></td><td>'.$notes.'</td></tr>';
```

As you can see, the query I am using is outdated because it is an INNER JOIN of just the projects table, not employees_projects. I do not know how to change my query to return all of the columns within timesheets ONLY for the projects that are assigned to that employee.

Any help?

EDIT

Sorry, I'll try to clarify. I am using php to build a form based upon the SELECT query shown above in the code for $result. This is correctly building a form but currently showing all projects found within the projects table (ie. projectID 1, projectID2, etc.). I need a SELECT query that will reutrn only the projects assigned to an employee based upon the employeeID/projectID combination of columns within employees_projects. After that, I will use my php code to build an INSERT query upon hitting submit.

Comment: Can you redesign time sheets? A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: What kind of query are you trying to write? You say you want to generate an `INSERT/UPDATE` query, but then say it's supposed to display projects. You don't display things with `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify. I am using php to build a form based upon the SELECT query shown above in the code for $result. This is correctly building a form but currently showing all projects found within the projects table (ie. projectID 1, projectID2, etc.). I need a SELECT query that will reutrn only the projects assigned to an employee based upon the employeeID/projectID combination of columns within employees_projects. After that, I will use my php code to build an INSERT query upon hitting submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join all the tables together:

```
SELECT ...
FROM projects AS p
JOIN employee_projects AS ep ON p.id = ep.projectID
JOIN employees AS e ON e.id = ep.employeeID
LEFT JOIN timesheets AS t ON t.projectID = p.id and t.employeeID = e.id
WHERE p.name = 'Bar'
```

I used a `LEFT JOIN` for `timesheets` so you'll still get a row for every employee assigned to the project, even if some of them haven't filled in timesheets.

It seems like there's some redundancy here that could be normalized, since both `employee_projects` and `timesheets` have `projectID` and `employeeID` foreign keys. It would be better if there were a single foreign key to the ID in the `employee_projects` table.

Comment: Hmm I think this is much better. Would this query work as well or will this result in redundancies?

select id, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, WeekEndingDate, Notes, Submitted, employees_projects.EmployeeID, employees_projects.ProjectID from timesheets INNER JOIN employees_projects on timesheets.EmployeeID=employees_projects.EmployeeID AND timesheets.ProjectID=employees_projects.ProjectID WHERE timesheets.EmployeeID=$eID

Comment: You can't format in comments. Add it as an update to the question.

Comment: In the question, you said **I would like to only populate a timesheet record for project Bar**. That's why I have `WHERE p.name = 'Bar'` in my answer.